# Translation Special Letters to English

Tags: java, unicode, special-characters

I am wondering if

1. there is any "standard" translation of special letters like `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, `ç`, `Ñ`, `Ã`, `æ`, etc. into English. A German would certainly transcribe `a` as `ae`, but an American would probably just use `a`. Is there any standard? and
2. if yes, is there any library in Java which covers signs contained in UTF code tables "Basic Latin" (`u0000-u007F`) and "Latin-1 Supplement" (`u0080-u00FF`)?

Thx

Comment: This problem is called [romanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization). It is a tough problem :)

Comment: What does question 2 mean? By "sign", do you mean "character", and what does it mean for a library to "character" a glyph?

Comment: And by 'to "character" a glyph', i mean 'to "cover" a glyph'. Sorry. Not enough coffee this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution for your problem is transliteration. 
Check those links below:

[ICU Home page](http://site.icu-project.org/)

[Transliterator class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html)

Comment: Did you finally come up with a solution? Please share.

Answer (score 0):

**I had an idea, but it doesn't work. It's just complete rubbish. Don't try this.**

*I'm not sure if there is a standard as such.*

*One thing you could do would be to [normalise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) the character into the NFKD form, which breaks all characters down to their most basic elements, such as base letters and combining marks, then filter out just the ASCII characters. This would take `æ` to `ae`, `ä` to `a`, and all other single characters with diacritics to their base characters.*

*This won't make Germans happy, though.*

Comment: I don’t think æ is affected in normalization; it certainly should not, as it has no decomposition in Unicode. The same applies to e.g. Ł (even though the stroke might be intuitively seen as a diacritic, it is not defined that way in Unicode; Ł is a base letter with no decomposition).

Comment: You're right, this doesn't work. Some ligatures do have a compatibility decomposition (eg the ffi ligature), but not all. I didn't realise that (well, i knew that w didn't decompose to vv, i suppose). Nor that some derived letters aren't treated as modifications of their base letters. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

With the java [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) you can split ä into a + combining diacritic mark. And then you can simply remove all diacritic marks.

```
String normalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
String ascii = normalizedString.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "");
```